# how to get a 1 pixel wide skeleton?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I would like to get a 1 pixel wide skeleton from a binary vessel tree. The skeleton I  get after applying my code has some small false branches and is not 1 pixel wide. How to get a perfect skeleton?

Vessels were enhanced using Frangi filter and the binary tree was extracted after having performed thresholding. This is the image at that point:
[image: binary vessel map]

Then, thinning is performed to get the skeleton:

```
% getting the skeleton
Iskel = bwmorph(Out,'thin',8);
figure,imshow(Iskel);

% because of the discontinuity in my skeleton, I've applied imdilate to create continuity 
se = strel('square',2);
Skel = imdilate(Iskel, se);
figure,imshow(Skel); title('Skel 8');
```

I expect the output to be one pixel wide skeleton but actually am not sure that mine is one pixel wide and also there are small false branches.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to bring it closer to a [mcve]? In particular, I suspect an image of what you have vs maybe what you expect would help a lot.

Comment: Did you try `bwskel`? If that doesn't work better than thinning, you need to upload your image and your result so we know what you're talking about here.

Comment: So what I see when applying your code to this image is a 1-pixel tick skeleton after the thinning. Of course after `imdilate` it no longer is 1 pixel thick, dilation makes it thicker. You could apply the dilation before the thinning to join up the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I used Zhang- Suen algorithm to create a skeleton from the original image. But the result may not be a single-pixel skeleton. So, I decided to create an algorithm to remove redundant pixels. Finally, I think got a single-pixel skeleton. You can consider my code as a solution.

Here is my Python implementation (I also add the result of my code below):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

"""
Input: image array (WxHX1)
Output: skeleton
"""
def zhang_suen_skeleton(img):
    # use zhang_suen algorithm
    skel = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(img)
    
    return skel

def check_connectivity(block_img):
    block_img[1][1] = 0
    (rows, cols) = np.nonzero(block_img)
    rows = sorted(rows)
    cols = sorted(cols)

    # condition 1
    for i in range(len(rows)-1):
        if rows[i+1] - rows[i] > 1:
            return False
    for j in range(len(cols)-1):
        if cols[j+1] - cols[j] > 1:
            return False
    
    # condition 2: check 4 corners
    if block_img[0][0] > 0:
        if block_img[0][1] == 0 and block_img[1][0] == 0:
            return False
    if block_img[2][0] > 0:
        if block_img[2][1] == 0 and block_img[1][0] == 0:
            return False
    if block_img[2][2] > 0:
        if block_img[2][1] == 0 and block_img[1][2] == 0:
            return False
    if block_img[0][2] > 0:
        if block_img[0][1] == 0 and block_img[1][2] == 0:
            return False

    return True

def single_pixelated(img):
    (rows, cols) = np.nonzero(img)
    result = img.copy()
    removed_pixels = []
    for (r, c) in zip(rows, cols):
        if (r, c) not in removed_pixels:
            block_img = result[r-1: r+2, c-1: c+2].copy()
            if np.sum(block_img) >=3*255:
                if check_connectivity(block_img):
                    result[r][c] = 0
                    removed_pixels.append((r, c))
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = cv2.imread('sample.png', 0)
    skel = zhang_suen_skeleton(img)
    single_skel = single_pixelated(skel)

    cv2.imwrite('single_skeleton.png', single_skel)
```

[image]

Comment: As a condition for removal, you just count the number of pixels in a 3x3 region. The skeleton condition is more complex than that. Note how your output still has many superfluous points (removing them would not disconnect the skeleton). A pixel in the middle of a line should have only two neighbors (3 pixels in a 3x3 region). You need to check the actual skeleton condition.

Comment: Usually the condition is stored as a table with 256 entries. You collect the 8 neighbors for a pixel onto a single 8-not digit, and look it up in the table. You can then fill the table manually. But the logic behind it is this: if a pixel has 0 or 1 neighbor, keep it. If a pixel has more neighbors, check to see if they form a single cluster or more; if a single cluster, remove, otherwise keep. A “single cluster” means that, when removing the pixel, the other pixels are all still connected. Go around the 8 neighbors in order, starting at an empty pixel, and count the clusters of 1s.